# Jasper Reports caching JasperReport file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I try to create a servlet based report service.

When app is running and I change the .jrxml file my app still
gives me report with no changed design, so I think that jasper cache it somewhere.

How can I turn it off or force to clear this cache?

```
 File compiledTemplate=new File(JASPER_COMPILED_TEMPLATES_PATH+  File.separator+templateName+".jasper");
        
 File template=new File(JASPER_TEMPLATES_PATH+File.separator+templateName+".jrxml");
        JasperReport jasperReport=null;
        

        if(compiledTemplate.exists()){
            compiledTemplate.delete();
        }
        
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(template.getAbsolutePath(),compiledTemplate.getAbsolutePath());
        jasperReport=(JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(compiledTemplate.getAbsolutePath());
        
        return jasperReport;
```

Comment: report must be recompiled after updating

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason to use compiledTemplate as file? Try like this:

```
File template=new File(JASPER_TEMPLATES_PATH+File.separator+templateName+".jrxml");
JasperReport jasperReport= JasperCompileManager.compileReport(template);
return jasperReport;
```

Comment: I cant do it this way. This is my boss decision.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Grails environment, delete all .jasper files in web-app/reports/ to refresh your report after making changes.

You can then recompile the .jrxml into new .jasper files.